# Using C# Lambda to split string and search value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a string with the following value:

```
0:12211,90:33221,23:09011
```

In each pair, the first value (before the `:` (colon)) is an employee id, the second value after is a payroll id.

So If I want to get the payroll id for employee id 23 right now I have to do:

```
var arrayValues=mystring.split(',');
```

and then for each `arrayValues` do the same:

```
var employeeData = arrayValue.split(':');
```

That way I will get the key and the value.

> Is there a way to get the Payroll ID by a given employee id using lambda?

If the employeeId is not in the string then by default it should return the payrollid for employeeid 0 zero.

Comment: What does lambda have to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Linq pipeline and anonymous objects:

```
"0:12211,90:33221,23:09011"
.Split(',')
.Select(x => x.Split(':'))
.Select(x => new { employeeId = x[0], payrollId = x[1] })
.Where(x=> x.employeeId == "23")
```

Results in this:

```
{
  employeeId = "23",
  payrollId = "09011"
}
```

These three lines represent your data processing and projection logic:

```
.Split(',')
.Select(x => x.Split(':'))
.Select(x => new { employeeId = x[0], payrollId = x[1] })
```

Then you can add any filtering logic with `Where` after this the second `Select`

Comment: Looks nice, how can I return the value of 12211 if the employeeid is not in the string.. so the default payrollid is 12211 for employeeid 0.?

Comment: Add the logic for that directly in the line `payrollId = x[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that

```
"0:12211,90:33221,23:09011"
            .Split(new char[] { ',' })
            .Select(c => {
                var pair = c.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(pair[0], pair[1]);
            })
            .ToList();
```

You have to be aware of validations of data

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd use a dictionary. Especially if you're going to do more than one lookup.

```
Dictionary<int, int> employeeIDToPayrollID = "0:12211,90:33221,23:09011"
    .Split(',') //Split on comma into ["0:12211", "90:33221", "23:09011"]
    .Select(x => x.Split(':')) //Split each string on colon into [ ["0", "12211"]... ]
    .ToDictionary(int.Parse(x => x[0]), int.Parse(x => x[1]))
```

and now, you just have to write `employeeIDtoPayrollID[0]` to get 12211 back. Notice that `int.Parse` will throw an exception if your IDs aren't integers. You can remove those calls if you want to have a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Split` along with `string.Substring`.

```
var result = 
      str.Split(',')
         .Where(s => s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf(":",StringComparison.Ordinal)) == "23")
         .Select(s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf(":",StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1))
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

if this logic will be used more than once then I'd put it to a method:

```
public string GetPayrollIdByEmployeeId(string source, string employeeId){
    return  source.Split(',')
          .Where(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(":", StringComparison.Ordinal)) == employeeId)
          .Select(s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf(":", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1))
          .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have more than three pairs in the string (how long is that string, anyway?) you can convert it to a `Dictionary` and use that going forward.

First, `split` on the comma and then on the colon and put in a `Dictionary`:

```
var empInfo = src.Split(',').Select(p => p.Split(':')).ToDictionary(pa => pa[0], pa => pa[1]);
```

Now, you can write a function to lookup payroll IDs from employee IDs:

```
string LookupPayrollID(Dictionary<string, string> empInfo, string empID) => empInfo.TryGetValue(empID, out var prID) ? prID : empInfo["0"];
```

And you can call it to get the answer:

```
var emp23prid = LookupPayrollID(empInfo, "23");
var emp32prid = LookupPayrollID(empInfo, "32");
```

If you just have three employees in the string, creating a `Dictionary` is probably overkill and a simpler answer may be appropriate, such as searching the string.